# MongoDB 3.6.2 $out fails with duplicate key error

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Here is the aggregation query which fails unexpectedly:

```
db.sq_lesson_user_lessons.aggregate([
  {
   "$match": {
     lesson_id: { 
       "$in": [ObjectId("5bb6ec0a178353bbdecdd94d"), ObjectId("5bbf1e611783538013ce2f0a")] 
     },
     status: { "$in": ['featured','started','pending','completed'] }
   }
  },
  {
   "$project": {
     _id: 1,
     user_profile_id: 1,
     status: 1,
     lesson_id: 1
   }
  },
  {
   "$out": "analytics_company_5bb6039598f17297c964fc54_sq_user_lessons"
  }
])

assert: command failed: {
    "operationTime" : Timestamp(1542715086, 67659),
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "insert for $out failed: { lastOp: { ts: Timestamp(1542715086, 67657), t: 39 }, connectionId: 242551, err: \"E11000 duplicate key error collection: api_smartquest_co_production.tmp.agg_out.637145 index: _id_ dup key: { : ObjectId('5bf22e554b8a982ada5e2828') }\", code: 11000, codeName: \"DuplicateKey\", n: 0, ok: 1.0, operationTime: Timestamp(1542715086, 67657), $clusterTime: { clusterTime: Timestamp(1542715086, 67658), signature: { hash: BinData(0, 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000), keyId: 0 } } }",
    "code" : 16996,
    "codeName" : "Location16996",
    "$clusterTime" : {
        "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1542715086, 67659),
        "signature" : {
            "hash" : BinData(0,"wvZz15/714/PHqAWywLpZlP4azQ="),
            "keyId" : NumberLong("6606442824109916161")
        }
    }
} : aggregate failed
```

This aggregation results in about 300 thousand records. Sometimes the aggreagation works and sometimes it fails.

Comment: Are you certain it's this code where the error is throwing? I ask because there is nothing really being manipulated here at all, and such an error would typically come where you did an `$unwind` or similar stage within the pipeline. Also the `to_a` is pointless here since when a pipeline contains `$out` it returns no result.

Comment: Drop `temp_collection`, or at least remove indexes from there.

Comment: @AlexBlex `$out` overwrites ( read drops ) the collection anyway and the dup key is on `_id` in the error. At least that's the "current" behavior before 4.2, and the syntax for anything else is different anyway. So it's far more likely that this is not the code which is producing the error, just as stated earlier.

Comment: Hmm, I read https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/#replace-existing-collection as it keeps the indexes. Agree on `_id` point tho.

Comment: This is the exact aggregation which is throwing the error. To be precise about the query. Here are the match conditions I am using. { :$match => { :lesson_id => { :$in => ["id1","id2"] }, :status => { :$in => ['completed','started'] } } }

Comment: This is executed using a ruby driver. Hence the syntax looks different. I will try this directly on mongo console and share more details soon. Btw. adding a group stage in the same pipeline seems to have fixed this for me for now: { :$group => { _id: "$_id", field1: { :$first => "$field1" } } }

Comment: Also, this sometimes works and sometimes fails with the dupkey error. I have a replica set configuration and this aggregation runs on a primary due to the $out stage.

Comment: Updated the question with the exact query and the result

Answer (score 3):

This was answered by [Daniel Hatcher](https://jira.mongodb.org/secure/ViewProfile.jspa?name=daniel.hatcher) from MongoDB with the below comment:

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-38212?focusedCommentId=2067603&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-2067603

CRUX of the answer is:

As the aggregation is searching through the large collection to return results, it is possible that some documents are being returned multiple times. This is related to one of the concepts within [MongoDB's read isolation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/read-isolation-consistency-recency/#read-uncommitted-and-multiple-document-write).